# Are module finite algebras over Noetherian semiperfect rings again semiperfect?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, noetherian, projective-module

Let $S$ be a Noetherian semiperfect ring (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring). Let $R$ be a module finite associative $S$-algebra. Then, is $R$ also a semiperfect ring? (Clearly, $R$ is Noetherian). If this is not true in general, what if I also assumed $S$ is commutative?

Comment: Now posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461288).